# unix word count tool counting characters across multiple lines

Tags: unix, word-count, wc

How would I apply the word count tool to a task of this nature:

```
Д

е

с

я

т

ь

д

н

е

й
```

I want to know how many characters appear but I want to ignore the white space in between the characters.

How can I specify that in the unix word count utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `tr` you can delete new lines and spaces like this:

```
$ tr -d '[\n ]' < file
Десятьдней
```

Then, pipe to `wc` with `-m` for chars:

```
$ tr -d '[\n ]' < file | wc -m
10
```